# Page change not getting reflected in angularjs while using routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, express

I am making an angularjs app,in which i am using Express as backend.The problem i'm facing is not being able to switch between my Html pages.Kindly help,i have tried a lot of tutorials but none of them worked.I guess there must be some problem in the path i am providing.
Here is my server.js
    `

```
var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var mysql      = require('mysql');
    var ejs = require('ejs');
    var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false});
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'root',
      password : '',
      database : 'test'

    });
    connection.connect();
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    //app.set('views', __dirname + 'views');//this is used because res.render('../template/goto_page_options.html', {values : city});
                                            //was not able to render the view
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        var path = require('path');
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('../template/login.html'));
        console.log("WOW");
    })
    app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
        var path = require('path');
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('../template/home.html'));
        console.log("home requested");
    })
```

`
This is my app.js

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider){

$routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        redirectTo: '/login'
    })
    .when('/home',{
        templateUrl:'home.html'
    })
    .when('/employee',{
        templateUrl:'employee.html'
    })
    .when('/login',{
        templateUrl:'login.html'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
```

}]);

This is my index.html

```
<body ng-app="starter">
            <div ng-view></div>
        <script src="http://localhost/try/www/js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost/try/www/js/server.js"></script>
</body>
```

my directory structure is

```
templates
  --login.html
  --home.hml
js
  --app.js
index.html
```

Comment: inside your directory sturcture where is employee.html file inside your templates folder

Comment: Where is the the refrence for $routeProvider  ?

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html, you have included

```
<script src="http://localhost/try/www/js/server.js"></script>
```

But in your directory structure, there is no such file.Check the console in your browser. There will be file not found error.
Also there is no such file

```
employee.html
login.html
```

Comment: This is an issue, the op should not have attempted to include the `server.js` on the client HTML. But this is unlikely the cause of the issue described

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't mention the correct directory structure.                        templates
  --login.html
  --home.hml
  --employee.html                                                                                                    --employee.html                                                                                       js
  --app.js                                                                                                       --server.js                                                                                  index.html